# When does mirin need refrigeration?

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, alcohol, japanese-cuisine

I've been trying to discover when mirin needs to be refrigerated. Unopened bottles aren't kept cold, but after opening answers seem to diverge.

I've read that traditional mirin is 14% alcohol by volume. Mine ("takara masamune mirin") is 12%, but doesn't appear to have added sweetener. The bottle itself doesn't mention storage after opening.

Should I be treating mirin more like (grape) wine and refrigerate after opening/consume quickly, or more like rice vinegar that can live in the pantry?

Answer (score 2):

I have never refrigerated a bottle of mirin in my life.  Not even the $12 fancy one.